# Dereference of a possible null reference (CS8602) after matching with object pattern in a switch expression

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types, switch-expression

I have the following code in a definition of a custom `IEqualityComparer<Uri?>`:

```
public bool Equals(Uri? x, Uri? y) => (x, y) switch
{
    (null, _) => false,
    (_, null) => false,
    ({}, {}) => x.Equals(y)
};
```

I'm getting a CS8602 warning on the `Equals` call in the last arm, telling me that there's a possibility `x` is `null` there. But I've just matched `x` against the object pattern `{}` which wouldn't match if `x` were `null`. Am I missing a possible control flow that causes `x` to be `null` in that branch or is it impossible and I should just bang-operator it away? Is it an analyzer bug or a known limitation?

### Update

It might be worth noting that this only happens if I destructure the tuple. This code is correct and gives no warnings:

```
public bool Equals(Uri? x, Uri? y) => x switch
{
    null => false,
    {} => x.Equals(y)
};
```

Comment: You can assign a property pattern to variable and use it in `Equals`, something like `({ } x1, { } y1) => x1.Equals(y1)`

Comment: I think this is a compiler bug that has been reported multiple times in different variants. One of the variants is https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37136